# List Slicing in Python

Tags: python

I have a list `numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]` where `len(numbers) = 5`. when I Slice it with `numbers[1:3]`, I got `[2, 3]` with 2 elements. so far no issues.

Now if assign this with more than 2 elements, say `numbers[1:3] = ['a','b','c','d]` , & re-check the `numbers`, I was expecting to get back `[1, 'a', 'b', 4, 5]`. chopping of `['c', 'd']`.
But I got `[1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 4, 5]` with `7` elements.

what happened here? why the list got extended?

Comment: You replaced 2 elements with 4 elements...

Comment: If you expected `[1, 'a', 'b', 4, 5]` you should use `numbers[1:3] = ['a','b','c','d'][:2]`